# Why are there so many devices in /dev?

Tags: devices

I read that your devices are listed in `/dev`. I do not have nearly as many devices attached to my system as there are listed in that directory. Why are there so many devices there? And how do I get informations about a particular one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every device in `/dev` corresponds to a physical device. The devices in `/dev` also include pseudo-devices allocated by the kernel which allows the kernel to interact with these abstractions using standard IO as if they were ordinary files. [Here is the device list as it appeared in the 2.6 kernel](http://www.lanana.org/docs/device-list/devices-2.6+.txt) which also provides some details for each (pseudo)device.

Answer (score 0):

`/dev` lists block and character devices the kernel has drivers for, but

- not all the device pseudo-files are necessarily physically present
- some devices such as network cards don't have nodes in `/dev`

To see what devices are actually present you're better off using something like the [`lshw`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw) command.